# how can i add to a key of the main dictionary, multiple sub dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i have this code right here:

```
dizionario = {}
social = "Instagram"

social_preso = "Facebook"
email_presa = "prova123@gmail.com"
passw_presa = "passw1234"

dizionario = {"Manager" :

                  {f"{social}" :
                       {"Social" : f"{social_preso}",
                        "E-Mail" : f"{email_presa}",
                        "Password" : f"{passw_presa}"}
                   }
              }
```

and i want to append to "Manager" another social.. so i want the text output(i'm using json.load) like this:

```
{
    "Manager": {
        "Instagram": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        }
    }

   
        "facebook": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        }
    }
}
```

but for now the output is:

```
{
    "Manager": {
        "facebook": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        }
    }
}{
    "Manager": {
        "facebook": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        }
    }
}
```

so basically every time a user insert social, email and password, it appends to "manager" and doesn't create another "manager"... how can i do it?

Comment: Could you share your code trying to insert the user?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
dizionario["Manager"]["facebook"] = {"Social" : f"{social_preso}",
                                     "E-Mail" : f"{email_presa}",
                                     "Password" : f"{passw_presa}"}
                                     }
```

to have multiple dictionary as JSON user List as below

```
[{Key: value}, {key: {k2: v2}}]
```

Comment: Thanks now it works, but i have this error with json:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 14 column 2 (char 320)

the output of the file is like this: 
{
    "Manager": {
        "Instagram": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        },
        "facebook": {
            "Social": "Facebook",
            "E-Mail": "prova123@gmail.com",
            "Password": "passw1234"
        }
    }
} 
But duplicated two times^^

Comment: can you be more specific with how you are trying to add the new key ..

Comment: dizionario["Manager"]["facebook"] = {"Social": f"{social_preso}",
                                         "E-Mail": f"{email_presa}",
                                         "Password": f"{passw_presa}"}

Comment: then there should be no json decode error as its considered as a dictionary in python.

Comment: yeah i know.. the problem is when i just try to add multiple dictionaries.. it gives me that error

Comment: actually i read that the problem is that json can't read multiple dictionaries... is there any other solution?

Comment: your dictionary should be inside a list [{...}, {.... }] this can be accessed as json as well